# how to grey out bootstrap modal when a spinner is showing?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I the example below, use can open a modal, type a message and then send it... It would take 2 seconds to send the message... I would like to show a spinner (which is already working) but also I want to background of the modal to be greyed-out while spinner is showing...

```js
$("#sendBtn").click(function() {
  $('.sending-message-spinner').show();
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
textarea {
   width: 100%;
   height: 80px;
}

@keyframes loading {
   0% {
       transform: rotate(0);
   }
   100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
   }
}

.sending-message-spinner {
   position: fixed;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 20;
   display: none;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   border: 8px solid #B0B0B0;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-top-color: #000;
   animation: loading .75s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="feedback-position sending-message-spinner">
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>type your message: </p>
            <Textarea> </textarea>
            <button id='sendBtn' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a class to CSS and have your JS call it when the button is clicked. I added to CSS `.myClass` and set the opacity in there, then called it in JS with `$("#myModal").addClass('myClass');` to add that class to `myModal` when the button is clicked. See here:

UPDATE:  Here I did it with an overlay div inside `myModal` This will grey out the modal without making it transparent.

```js
$("#sendBtn").click(function() {
  $("#overlay").show();
  $('.sending-message-spinner').show();
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#myModal").modal("hide");
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.sending-message-spinner {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 8px solid #B0B0B0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: #000;
  animation: loading .75s linear infinite;
}

#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>
  
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="feedback-position sending-message-spinner">
              </div>
            </div>
            <p>type your message: </p>
            <Textarea> </Textarea>
            <button id='sendBtn' type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but changing opacity doesn't look right... because in almost any real world scenario, there are other elements behind the modal which will appear through the modal if opacity is set to 0.5.

Comment: Gotchya.  I updated my answer to add an overlay div which greys it out instead of changing the opacity.  Please take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for this... I though it's easier to use jQuery's `show()` method to display the overlay, hope you don't mind me updating this in your answer.